# увеличение переменной в цикле jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

Надо считать номер записи в цикле. Есть такой код, но он всегда выдаёт единицу. Как пофиксить?

```
 {% set i = 0 %}
 {% for task in tasks %}
 {% set i = i + 1 %}
 {{ i }}
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: а что у вас закрывает {% endif %} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% set count = namespace(a=1) %}
{% for task in tasks %}
{{ count.a }}
{% set count.a = count.a + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: А просто `{{ loop.index }}` для вашего случая не подходит?